# Refer to multi dynamic ranges - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I m trying to refer to two different ranges in the same formula but i am not getting the desirable outcoume.

Ranges:

```
.Range("A3:A" & LastRowA)
.Range("H3:H" & LastRowH)
```

Complete formula used:

```
.Range("A3:A" & LastRowA, "H3:H" & LastRowH).Interior.Color = vbRed
```

What i get:

[image]

Desirable outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i manage to find an answer. in case someone face the same issue:

```
Union(.Range("A3:A" & LastRowA), .Range("H3:H" & LastRowH)).Interior.Color = vbRed
```